# How to let networkmanager repeat trying to connect DSL until succeeded?

Tags: networkmanager, ppp

I'm using nm-applet to dial up DSL pppoe connections. As there are a great number of users in my local network, I sometimes have to try many times to establish a successful connection.

I wonder is there some way to set nm-applet or network-manager repeat trying automatically until connecting successfully.

My system is Gentoo and desktop environment is Gnome.

Comment: Which distro are you using? I suspect this can be fixed by adding some custom settings to the pppoe configs, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: I am using a Gentoo box, and Gnome desktop environment. I have little knowledge about how ppp and pppoe stuff working. Can anyone give me some advice on where to start?

Comment: you need to modify pppd parameters if that could work.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify default `pppd` parameter (e.g place a `persist` parameter) , into 
`NetworkManager` 's source code , which is not guaranteed to work.

However , with powerful script you could try with some shit like the following , given you have a workable `pppd` connection , called `provider`

Keeping dialing until we have a default route configured:

```
while ! ip r | grep -q default
do
   pon provider
   sleep 10
done
```

If PPPoE connection is your only choice , why not configure `/etc/conf.d/net` for a persist connection ?